# Participio passato del verbo "prudere"

Tags: past-participle

Qualche giorno fa mi sono trovato a comporre una frase con il participio passato del verbo *prudere*, ma quando sono andato per pronunciarlo mi sono bloccato, imbarazzato, senza sapere che dire.

Secondo voi?

Comment: Per rispondere a una domanda così basta consultare un qualsiasi dizionario.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prudere è un verbo intransitivo della II coniugazione, coniugato nella forma attiva con nessun ausiliare, e soprattutto è un **verbo difettivo**, cioè mancante del participio presente e passato e di alcune persone del passato remoto.

Inoltre da un [post sul forum dell'Accademia della Crusca](http://forum.accademiadellacrusca.it/forum_10/interventi/4654.shtml.html) si legge:

> Verbi in «-údere» Tutti i verbi in -údere hanno il passato remoto
>   (nella 3a persona singolare) in -use e il participio passato in -uso.
>   Tranne prudere, il cui passato remoto è prudé o prudette: essendo un
>   verbo regolare, credo che il suo inesistente participio passato, se,
>   per qualche motivo, dovessimo coniarlo sei secoli dopo la prima
>   attestazione dell’infinito, non potrebbe essere altro che l’“orrido”
>   pruduto.
>
> È probabile che la difettività del verbo risieda nel fatto che nessuno
>   sente spesso la necessità di parlare di prurito in un tempo composto.
>   Forse perché la sensazione viene menzionata verbalmente solo nel
>   «presente della coscienza» (indicativo presente e imperfetto). Non
>   riesco a immaginare neanche un contesto per il pur esistente passato
>   remoto.
>
> In ogni caso, anche senza inventare un participio passato, si può
>   sempre usare, per i tempi composti, l’espressione «avere/sentire
>   prurito».

Comment: In realtà sembra che il participio presente sia accettato come "prudente".

Comment: Il participio passato non esiste ma il participio presente sì: prudente

Comment: Credo che prudente (aggettivo) sia un "falso amico" e che non abbia nulla a che vedere col verbo prudere (causare prurito)

Comment: Non ha molto a che fare con questa domanda, ma dal dizionario Treccani l'origine del latino *prudens* viene data come riduzione di *providens* (pronunciato qualcosa come *prouidens*), e non ha niente a che fare con *prudere* (che deriva dal latino *prurire* per dissimilazione). Il participio presente "etimologicamente corretto" di *prudere* è \**pruriente*, che però sembra in disuso e in ogni caso mai attestato fuori dal gergo medico.

Comment: Incidentalmente, sono in disaccordo con il post di Marco1971 sul forum dell'Accademia della Crusca: se decidessimo di dotare *prudere* di un participio passato, c'è un'ovvia scelta etimologica che non dovrebbe essere troppo difficile da "vendere" al grande pubblico: *prurito*.

Comment: "Proprio in quel momento così importante mi prudette il naso..."
Questo solo per smentire l'affermazione "Non riesco a immaginare neanche un contesto per il pur esistente passato remoto." Così come "mi prude il naso come non mi aveva mai ... prima". Insomma, in ossequio alla teoria dello sviluppo della lingua secondo l'anomalia, non esiste una ragione "logica" per la mancanza di alcuni tempi nei verbi difettivi, ma solo un, a volte casuale, mancato loro uso storico...

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE, @GigiMancinelli! Il tuo post non è una vera risposta alla domanda posta dall'OP, ma si tratta piuttosto di un commento a quanto affermato in questa risposta. Per questa ragione è stato convertito in commento.